# The meaning of << in groovy

Tags: groovy

What does `<<` mean in groovy?

See example here: http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/DatabaseDrivenSpecification

Answer (score 3):

It means different things depending what is on the left hand side. The simplest answer is that `x << y` compiles to `x.leftShift(y)`, you need to look at the JavaDoc of x's class to know what it will actually do.

The GDK adds implementations of `leftShift` to a number of core java classes, for example to append to the end of a list.

Edit: looking more closely at the Spock documentation, the specific case you've linked to appears to be something called a [multiple variable data pipe](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/data_driven_testing.html#multi-variable-data-pipes) rather than a normal use of `leftShift`.

```
where:
[a, b, c] << sql.rows("select a, b, c from maxdata")
```

will run the test once for each row returned by `sql.rows`, assigning the three values in the row to the three variables a, b and c.